# How to filter out double quote symbol with replaceAll function

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replaceall

i am trying to filter a string which containing " symbol.
I use the function replaceAll to eliminate unwanted " but errors appear.

Here is my expression:

```
str[i] = str[i].replaceAll("["]", null);
```

The error message is as follows:

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
>       - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
>       - The method replaceAll(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments 
>        (String)

I know that eclipse consider the " quote in [ ] as the boundary of the string I wanted to replace. Can anyone give me the correct expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
"["]"
```

the second quotation will consider the opening bracket as a string, and the other 2 characters(`]"`) will be a syntax error.

**solution:**
you need to escape the quotation mark so you can use the `quotation character` in the string/regex

```
 "[\"]"
```

adding null to the replacement parameter will generate an error, so don't put **null** put an empty string instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try `replaceAll("\"","");`

You don't want to use null, you want to use empty string.